# Mongodb exception: connect failed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2, mongo-repair

## Here's the environment:

1. Linux(x64): **16.04**
2. MongoDB: **3.2.15**

## Error:

```
root@system-test:~# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.15
connecting to: test
2017-07-25T07:31:28.528+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2017-07-25T07:31:28.530+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
root@system-test:~#
```

**When I tried to see the status I get this:**

```
root@system-test:~# sudo service mongodb status
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-07-25 07:45:32 UTC; 1min 8s ago
  Process: 1721 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
 Main PID: 1721 (code=exited, status=14)

Jul 25 07:45:32 system-test systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Jul 25 07:45:32 system-test systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Jul 25 07:45:32 system-test systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 25 07:45:32 system-test systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

## How it happened:

I tried to stop MongoDB and did the following

**`sudo service mongo stop`** [This didn't work].

Then i tried **`kill - 2 <PID>`** [Seem didn't worked too]

But after this command **`#mongo`** stopped working and getting the above error.

Please help guys

Comment: Please attach last 20 lines of MongoDB log file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> sudo service mongo stop [This didn't work]

As MongoDB BOL  [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/) is an interactive JavaScript shell interface to `MongoDB`, which provides a powerful interface for systems administrators as well as a way for developers to test queries and operations directly with the database. `mongo` also provides a fully functional JavaScript environment for use with a `MongoDB`.

And [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/) is the primary daemon process for the `MongoDB` system. It handles data requests, manages data access, and performs background management operations.

As simple language we can say that **mongo** is shell interface for `MongoDB`. And **mongod** is server , which handles data requests, manages data access, and performs background management operations.

So, in place `sudo service mongo stop` it should be the below mention command

> sudo service **mongod** stop

As MongoDB documented [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-red-hat/) Some of basic procedure to check `MongoDB` services in `RHEL` is as mention below:

**Start MongoDB**

```
sudo service mongod start
```

**Stop MongoDB**

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

**Restart MongoDB**

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

**Verify that MongoDB has started successfully**

```
sudo chkconfig mongod on
```

**Begin using MongoDB**

Start a `mongo` shell on the same host machine as the `mongod`

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Answer (score 2):

As your service mongodb status tells, your mongod process don't exists. So, if you try to connect (with mongo -program) to your mongod, you cannot.

So, restart your mongod `sudo service mongodb restart`, try now to connect it `mongo`.

If you want to see what happens when you shutdown, start following mongodb.log `tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` and then in other terminal say `sudo service mongodb stop`, some times shutdown process can take quite long time.. As startup process too.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into same issue. But was able to resolve by completely removing mongo first

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

Then performing following

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y mongodb
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

You can refer to following link for the same: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 2):

This question is for Linux, but for fellow windows users who found their way here and want a windows solution...

the problem is your Mongodb service is stopped.
So do the following steps:

```
    1) cntrl-alt-del and open your task manager
    2) click on 'services'
    3) scroll down to MongoDB
    4) right click and hit 'start' (or 'restart')
```

go back to your mongo.exe file and your mongo shell should work now

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is related to a remote access, here is the solution for anyone who has the problem

show iptable rules line numbers

```
sudo iptables -L --line-numbers
```

The output will be something like this

```
...
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
3    INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
4    INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
5    INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
6    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
7    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
8    ACCEPT     tcp  --  172.16.84.102        anywhere             tcp dpt:27017 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
3    FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
4    FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
5    FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
6    FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
7    FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
8    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
9    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
...
```

The problem is caused by the rule

```
7    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Delete it but keep security team informed about this operation

Here is how to delete a rule using the type ( input in out case ) and line number ( 7 in out case )

```
sudo iptables -D INPUT 7
```

Now test your connection to mongo db from other machines and it has to be working now.

Note: This solution will work if you already configured the /etc/mongod.conf by:

- commenting

  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
- Adding

  bindIpAll: true
- Uncommenting security and adding

  authorization: 'enabled'

Enjoy it :)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem on a Windows OS. Here the steps to get MongoDB up and running.

1. Check that the `PATH` environment variable contains the following string:
   `;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin;`

   > **Note**
   > `5.0` is the installed version in my system, in your case it may very.
2. Open the windows services via:

   - <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
   - Type: `services.msc`
   - Hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
     It then shows the list of available services.
3. Start the `MongoDB Server` service manually.
4. Open the command prompt

   - <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
   - Type: `cmd`
   - Hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
5. At the Command Prompt enter:

   - `C:\> mongo`
   - Hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

You should receive a successful connection.

[image]